# C# NUnit not running tests asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, .net-4.5

I have written the following test trying to make use of the new async/await keywords available in .NET 4.5:

```
    [Test]
    public async void DefaultFilesValid()
    {
        LogTest(log);
        var libraryTasks = new List<Task<string>>();
        foreach (var def in LibrariesModel.LibraryDefinitions)
        {
            IViewModel viewModel = (IViewModel)ReflectionUtility.CreateNew(def.ModelType);
            var libraries = def.LibraryFiles.Where(f => def.IsDefaultFile(f)).ToArray();
            foreach(var library in libraries)
            {
                var libraryTask = LoadEmbeddedLibraryAsync(viewModel, library);
                libraryTasks.Add(libraryTask);
            }
        }

        // Wait for the results
        var libraryErrors = await Task.WhenAll(libraryTasks);
        var errors = libraryErrors.SelectMany(m => m);
        Assert.True(!errors.Any(), String.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors));
    }

    private async Task<string> LoadEmbeddedLibraryAsync(IViewModel viewModel, string library)
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() =>
        {
            var libraryDef = viewModel.Library;
            var libraryMessage = String.Format("The default library '{0}' of the type '{1}' ", library, libraryDef.LibraryName);
            try
            {
                // Open the library
                viewModel.Open(library, library: true);

                // Check that the hash is as expected
                var fileHash = libraryDef.GetDefaultFileHash(library);
                var hash = viewModel.Source.GetStatewiseHashCode().ToString();
                if (fileHash != hash)
                    return libraryMessage + String.Format("has been modified, model hash was '{0}' but '{1}' was expected.", hash, fileHash);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return String.Format("failed to open: {0}", ExceptionUtility.JoinExceptionMessages(ex));
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
```

However the code is executing synchronously, can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your unit test from `async void` to `async Task`. NUnit supports `async void` unit tests only from v2.6.2 onward for v2, and only supported them in v2.9.6 for v3 (support in v3 has already been removed in v2.9.7). `async void` tests require NUnit to provide a special context, which changes the behavior of `await` (and possibly `StartNew`, though I haven't tested that).

As a side note:

- Use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`. I have a blog post describing [why](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).
- Use `Task.Run` to *call* methods, not to *implement* (fake-)asynchronous methods. I have another blog post describing [why](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).